# LYX error \triangleq symbol not def'ed

Tags: lyx

when trying to preview my article in LYX, I got the following error:

> ```
> f\left(x\right)\triangleq  
>                                \lim_{\delta x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f  \left(...
> The control sequence at the end of the top line  
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have  
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct  
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,  
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

I believe it refers to the `\triangleq` symbol.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{amssymb}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know this command. Isn't it `\trianglelefteq` or `\trianglerighteq`, per chance?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, it supposed to be a equal sign with a triangle above pointing upwards ("definition")...

Comment: I am new to LYX (and LATEX). What is {amssymb} and how do I use it?

Comment: It is a maths font package, which comes with `amsfonts`. What is your distribution?

Comment: I added \usepackage{amssymb} to Document->Settings->LaTex Preamble and it solved the problem... Thank you!